# SourceForgeNet - санкции

Tags: проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Проект криптографии на [С](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) и [PHP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) заблокировали по IP. Какие возможные есть варианты выкладывания проекта?

[Проект на SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/shifr/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: гитхаб?.. почему нет

Comment: github и лиса не отвечает

Comment: Вы можете подробнее описать вопрос?.. Ваш проект заблокировали и Вам его необходимо разместить?.. или же Вам нужно скачать какой-то проект, но Вас заблокировали?.. если так, то что это за проект?

Comment: А через прокси-сервер выйти? Другое дело, что если проект нарушает правила сайта, то его опять заблокируют. Так что надо проблему решать с проектом, а не с возможностями обхода блокировки.

Comment: после нового года посещаемость нулевая моего проекта и я не могу качать другие проекты.

Comment: Киньте тут линк на ваш проект

Comment: @avp Удалил от злости, вечером выложу.

Comment: Восстановил проект https://sourceforge.net/projects/shifr/ Своё качать так и не могу. @avp

Comment: Восстановил проект https://sourceforge.net/projects/shifr Своё качать так и не могу. @Михаил Ребров

Comment: а где вы находитесь, что Ваши запросы блокируют? в Крыму или еще где?

Comment: Именно там, посмотрите ip. Я переживаю, отдаёт сайт скачивать из другого места или нет? @Михаил Ребров

Comment: скачал нормально (со второго раза правда, с первого какой-то глюк на сайте был, но потом все норм)...в интерфейсе у меня тоже нет никаких предупреждений. насколько понял сам проект не заблокирован. просто вас ограничили в правах как пользователя и все...при этом другие пользователи без проблем могут скачать ваш проект.

Comment: Если вы качали `php.zip` то спасибо, а то у меня аж нервы пошли в разнос. @Михаил Ребров

Comment: сначала скачал `с20200111.tar.gz`, после вашего последнего комментария скачал `php20200111.zip`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, да, качает. Жаль, конечно, но вам придется работать через Proxy